# Phonegap application isn't showing properly on iOS emulator or device

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

During the development process of my phonegap/cordova application I used "phonegap serve". When I access my application through "phonegap serve" with the Phonegap app, the application is working as expected.

However when I perform a "phonegap run ios" on either the emulator or iPhone itself, the jQuery Mobile collapsable set is not seen on the second half of the screen.

Here is the latest committed code on the development branch: 
https://github.com/kacole2/jsmap1/tree/placesAPI

This is how the application looks when viewed with "phonegap serve"
[image: working]

This is how the application looks when viewed on the emulator or iOS device with "phonegap run ios"
[image: not working]

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: why the down votes?? I'm looking for some help and the codebase has changed since the last post

Comment: Have you looked at the console log of the browser see if there are any warnings or errors?

Comment: @rdodev yes i have. nothing comes up when i use the Safari developer plugin. its not even showing the initial call-out to google maps for the map to load. looks like as soon as i launch the emulator, then go to Safari -> developer tools -> iPhone -> index.html, everything has already ran. Any idea how to get those tools to display *before* i launch the emulator?

Comment: Something tells me your page isn't bootstrapping correctly (not to point the obvious). Are you loading jQ or any library from a CDN?

Comment: @rdodev yes. jQ and jQ Mobile are both coming from Google CDN. Should I try to keep them local?

Comment: Yes, load them locally. And/or make sure you have whitelisted the urls

Comment: @KennyColemanyes, please load them locally. if anything because it removes variables.

Comment: I moved the files local and the problem still persists. In addition, now that the files are local, I can no longer run "phonegap serve" because I'm getting an error that states: Error: EMFILE: Too many opened files.

Comment: I fixed the "Too many opened files" issue since it was a mac problem. When I run "phonegap serve" and all files are hosted locally everything is working. So the issue still persists with running it on an emulator and the device itself.  Thanks for your help so far

Comment: @KennyColeman I'm willing to bet there's an issue in your plist with permissions and network white listing. If the serve works (which is browser based) but emulator doesn't, it's a tell-tale of configuration issues.

Comment: here is what i'm struggling to understand. The app is pulling google fonts from fonts.googleapis.com because the header font is correct. so it can actually get out to the network. It can also render the initial map so its talking to google maps apis as well... i just don't know why jQuery & jQuery Mobile is failing (even with the files local). So I'm not sure what network I need to white list. Sorry for being a noob. this is my first phonegap project

Comment: It can be outright frustrating working with cordova not knowing why things aren't working is one of them. All I can say is that it takes a lot of trial and error to figure out and that goes beyond the scope of stackoverflow. Specially because there's no error in the log/console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65224/discussion-between-kenny-coleman-and-rdodev).

Comment: To see the output in the console when the app starts up, open the developer tools in safari, and then refresh using Ctrl+R or Cmd+R (Mac)

Comment: @JBaczuk THANK YOU!! Please add an answer because this helped me find the solution so I can give you credit. I was getting an "Over Query Limit" response back from google maps APIs. I created a setTimeout function and now it's working! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view the console output (javascript) for an app with a webview (like Phonegap), do one of the following:

Safari (iOS):
On the device, disable private browsing and enable web inspector.  In Safari enable development tools and you should see the device in the Developer menu.  Select it and use Cmd+R to refresh and get the output from app startup.

Chrome (Android):
Navigate to chrome://inspect/#devices and open the webview.  Use ctrl+R to refresh and see the output from app startup.  Also, make sure that debugging is enabled on the Android device.

Comment: Thank you again.. come to find out I was getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT return status' from google maps. I added a setTimeout function and it now slows down the rate at which they are sent.

Comment: Glad it helped, I can't do development with Phonegap without watching the console constantly.