# Ajax request failing in cordova/phonegap app on real device

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova, double-click

I'm building a **Cordova 4.0 jQuery Mobile 1.4.2** Android app and I'm having issues with a particular AJAX call. I've looked for similar questions and already implemented the solutions there with no success.

Here's what happens:

I have the following AJAX call:

```
var request = $.ajax({
        type: "GET" ,
        crossDomain: true,
        url: 'http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/adx?iu=/XXX/YYY&sz=300x50&c=123456789'
    });

    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){

        console.log(response);
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.error("DFP Plugin Error: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
    });
```

When I run my app in my computer's browser, that request works perfectly. However, when I build and debug the app from a **real device**, the request fails giving this error: `{"readyState":0, "responseText":"", "status":0, "statusText":"error"}`

I've already enabled `$.support.cors = true;` and `$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;`, and I already have `<access origin="*" />)` in my config.xml file.

Could someone help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Error from server side.

Comment: @HanhLe not sure, if that was the case it wouldn't work in either situation, but it works from desktop browser...

Comment: Can you tell us your console output?  Use this to get the console output: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27044611/3499115

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this is not the kind of answer I was expecting, but this what I did to solve this: create a completely new Cordova 4.0 project and copy there the www folder from the other one. Then build and run in eclipse as usual and everything worked **without changing one single line of code anywhere in the project**.

I realized the problem wasn't in the code because I noticed that other AJAX calls that I had in the app (and used to work fine) were also failing.

So I don't know if this is some Cordova 4.0 bug or something, but at some point AJAX stopped working. I'm posting this in case someone runs into the same issue.

Comment: same issue here... sick. :/

Comment: It happened to me too. But after googling "cordova ajax call not work" I uninstalled my app from the device and emulator, wipe emulator, delete emulator and create a new one, and oh, of course, fiddle with my dns server settings, since my call from dnsmasq was kinda funny.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was upgrading from cordova 3.7 to cordova 5
Here is what solved it for me: add the plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: Link to docs: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html and the command: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

Answer (score 3):

Because of New Content Security Policy for android Ajax Requests are blocked.

try following and see if that works.

Open your config.xml

Replace

```
<access origin="*" />
```

With

```
<access origin="http://*" />
<access origin="https://*" />
```

prepare the phonegap project and build it again and check on real device.

Regards,
Jagat

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I was just missing the following plugin:

cordova-plugin-whitelist

After I installed it, remove the android platform, re-added the android platform, build and run, it worked!