# Ajax call to REST service returns status:0

Tags: android, ajax, json, cordova, rest

Ajax call from cordova android application to the REST service in the localhost, returns

```
{ "readyState" : 0, "responseText" : "", "statusText" : "error" }
```

I've added `<access origin="*" />` to the config.xml

```
    $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",    
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
        url: "http://10.0.3.2:8080/ServiceProject/rest/vsa-service/auth",
        success: function(result){            
            if(result.auth){ 
                window.localStorage["authentication"] = result.authCode;
                window.localStorage["authDetails"] = result.details;                                    
                $.mobile.changePage("#home");    
            }                
            else{
                navigator.notification.alert('Login failed. Try again.', function() {});                        
            }
        },
        error: function(err){
            navigator.notification.alert('Error occurred unexpectedly.' + JSON.stringify(err) , function() {});
        }    
    });
```

I'm using GenyMotion as the Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27047703/1213223) answer, I created  entirely a new cordova project and copied the www folder in to it. Then build and run worked. the AJAX call works fine. There was no any changes made to the code.