# ajax GET request returning Status and ReadyState 0

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am using the following code to make a ajax request, in Cordova app

```
        $.ajax(rssUrl, {ct: id, crossDomain: true}).done(
                function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var object = $(this);           //extracting context

                    var cntxt = object[0].ct;

                    rssReader.parse(data, textStatus, jqXHR, true, cntxt)
                }
            )
            .fail(alErr);
```

**This request is working fine in the ripple emulators**,but doing a build on Physical android device I keep getting the alErr output (the status and readyState of jqXHR object is 0)

Specfically this is not working for http://www.footballnewsguru.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Liverpool?alt=json&max-results=10
It works for other feeds i am accessing

The first answer from [jQuery Ajax - Status Code 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0) does not seem to be for my app, as the CSP is allowing the request in emulators, there is no DNS problem.

I have been searching for a solution for hours, but mostly they are about the browser refreshing or form submitting before ajax request is sent, but neither are applicable to my case.

[EDIT]

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

here is the meta for CSP.
Encoding the URL did not work either.

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: No there are no errors in the Visual Studio Javascript console

Comment: @TZaman could you try encoding the URL before making AJAX call as you said its not working only for particular feed?

Comment: Can you post your CSP meta tag also?

Comment: Sorry for the late edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here:
[Ajax request failing in cordova/phonegap app on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027736/ajax-request-failing-in-cordova-phonegap-app-on-real-device)

The last answer worked for me by adding

```
<access origin="http://*" />
<access origin="https://*" />
```

to config.xml, still wondering why

```
<access origin="http://www.footballnewsguru.com" />
```

dose not work.